# MultipleValidationErrors errors on dynamodb upload from json file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm getting some upload errors when i try to upload my json file to dynamodb but can't seem to figure it out. The errors I get are these:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Expected params.Item['lastname'] to be a structure",
      "code": "InvalidParameterType",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '0' found in params.Item['lastname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '1' found in params.Item['lastname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '2' found in params.Item['lastname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '3' found in params.Item['lastname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '4' found in params.Item['lastname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '5' found in params.Item['lastname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '6' found in params.Item['lastname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Expected params.Item['firstname'] to be a structure",
      "code": "InvalidParameterType",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '0' found in params.Item['firstname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '1' found in params.Item['firstname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '2' found in params.Item['firstname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.907Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '3' found in params.Item['firstname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '4' found in params.Item['firstname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '5' found in params.Item['firstname']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Expected params.Item['employeeid'] to be a structure",
      "code": "InvalidParameterType",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '0' found in params.Item['hrs']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '1' found in params.Item['hrs']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '2' found in params.Item['hrs']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '3' found in params.Item['hrs']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '4' found in params.Item['hrs']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '5' found in params.Item['hrs']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '6' found in params.Item['hrs']",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
    }
  ],
  "time": "2016-10-20T19:16:11.908Z"
}
```

my data file that I"m trying to upload looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "lastname": "abc",
    "firstname": "dfx",
    "employeeid": 78,
    "hrs": [
      {
        "availhrs": "123",
        "ttlhrs": "111",
        "bllhrs": "98",
        "rto": "16",
        "ondeckhrs": "0",
        "nonbllhrs": "0",
        "employeeid": 78,
        "dtmonth": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "clientid": 1,
        "clientId": 1,
        "employeeId": 78
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I created my table like this:

```
var params = {
    TableName : "ach3",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "employeeid", KeyType: "HASH" }, //Sort key
        { AttributeName: "lastname", KeyType: "RANGE" }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "lastname", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "employeeid", AttributeType: "N" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};
```

and this is how I'm trying to upload the table:

```
var allACH = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('ach.json', 'utf8'));


allACH.forEach(function(movie) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "ach3",
        Item: {
            "lastname":  movie.lastname,
            "firstname": movie.firstname,
            "employeeid": movie.employeeid,
            "hrs":  movie.hrs
        }
    };

    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to add item", movie.employeeid, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("PutItem succeeded:", movie.employeeid);
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The "Item" object needs to have the type information per property:
So you need something like

```
Item: {
        "lastname":  {S: movie.lastname},
        "firstname": {S: movie.firstname},
        "employeeid": {S: movie.employeeid},
        "hrs": {N: String(movie.hrs) }
    }
```

This is telling the API that "lastname" is of type string (S).

Hope that helps

Comment: Also, the "hrs" is itself a json document, but in your case you are declaring it as a number.  Remove "hrs" for now and see if it will work for the  "lastname", "firstname", and "employeeid"